# Column reference by number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to calculate a set of data that I can reuse without having to update the column references every month. The source data looks like this:

[image]

As the month gets closed, the data will get updated, and the header goes from **'Forecast'** to **'Actuals'**.

I am able to find and display the latest month of **'Actuals'** ("2017 05") & the first month of **'Forecast'** ("2017 06"), and their corresponding column numbers (49 & 50).

Now I need a **SUMIFS** formula where I can define the `sum_range` using these column numbers rather than `"Data!AW:AW"` and `"Data!AX:AX"`, so that it will automatically update as the data changes.

I did find some solutions using **VBA**, which is not something I'm comfortable dabbling with. Is there a way to solve it using normal Excel formula?

Comment: Hi @excel_user.  Questions about standard excel formulae are best sent to https://superuser.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

Try using INDIRECT() along with ADDRESS(). You haven't shared some sample data so can't help further.